# Observable stream with a conditional call

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have an observable stream that makes two calls after the initial object is retrieved using two id's found in the object. One of the id's is optional and may or may not be there. The siteId is the optional id. If it is found I must make a call exactly as I have with getTeam. How do I make conditional calls? The only way I was able to get this to work was by checking for the id in the subscribe method and making a call from there. However the code will have nested subscribes which I want to avoid.

```
private getZone() {
    this.spinner.show();

    this.zonesService.getZone(this.zoneId)
      .map(response => {
        this.zone = response['group'];
        this.teamId = this.zone['TeamId'];
        this.siteId = this.zone['SiteId'];
        return this.zone;
      })
      .flatMap(() => this.teamsService.getTeam(this.teamId))
      .map(response => {
        if (response['team']) {
          this.team = response['team'];
          if (this.team['personal']) { this.team['name'] = 'Personal Team'; }
          this.zone['teamName'] = this.team['name'];
        }
        return response;
      })
      .subscribe(
        _data => {
          if (this.zone['personal']) { this.zone['name'] = 'My Personal Zone'; }
          if (this.siteId) {
            this.sitesService.getSite(this.siteId)
              .subscribe(
                _data => {
                  this.site = _data['site'];
                }
              );
          }

          this.spinner.hide();
          this.loading = false;
        }
      );
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the forkJoin() method inside your first flatMap()

```
this.zonesService.getZone(this.zoneId)
    .flatMap(response => {
        this.zone = response['group']

        if(this.zone.SiteId){
            // make these 2 api calls in parallel
            return Observable.forkJoin(
                this.getTeam(this.zone.TeamId),
                this.getSite(this.zone.SiteId)
            );
        }else{
            // make single api call
            return this.getTeam(this.zone.TeamId);
        }
    }).subscribe(response => {
        // note that your response will be different based on the flatMap(). 
        // When you do the 2 calls in parallel, your response = [getTeamResponse, getSiteResponse]
        // but when you just do the single call, your response = getTeamResponse
        // so you'll need a check in here to account for that
    });
```

So what is functionally happening is you make your initial api call. Then if that response returns a site id, make the team & site calls in parallel, else make the single team call.

Here is a good resource on forkJoin: https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-multiple-http-requests-with-rxjs

Answer (score 0):

If i'm not wrong, you got all the values you need to use on your first call ( zonesService.getZone ) if you split your stream at this point ( maybe share it) and make a separate call for the other 2 endpoints, you could handle both in parallel, and use a "null" observable for the sitesService.getSite ( defaultIfEmpty operator ) then finally merge em again with a zip function.

Comment: Thank you. Im just learning RXJS. Since my job is so involved in extra responsibilities at this time doing both front and back end I have not had the time to really get into the docs. Your solution was probably awesome. Although I did tried, I did not have enough background knowledge to put it together in code. I would have really liked to learn from your suggestion. If you have time to add a code example that would be cool.